# Keep getting prompted for password to access SharePoint site

Tags: 2010, login, windows-7

So a colleague of mine keeps getting prompted for a password every time she accesses SharePoint. I have sat with her and changed the password in the credential manager to the correct version but now, every time she tries to access SharePoint, she is still prompted for her password even though we're a 100% sure the one in the credential manager is correct.

Another colleague and myself have had this issue before and it got resolved by correcting the passwords in the credential manager but now it won't..

We are using SharePoint 2010 with Windows 7 as OS.

Does anyone have any idea on why this might be occurring?

Comment: is your site added in trusted zone?

Comment: It is now, and she is no longer prompted. Thanks for the solution, I would've never thought of this myself..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As my comment worked for you, I am going to add it as answer. In the future it may help others.

Actually, once I had this issue and then I added my site in trusted zone and my issue was solved.

1. From IE go to **Internet Options**

[image]

2. Go to **Security** Tab and select **Trusted sites**
3. Now click on **Sites**

[image]

4. Add your site and click **Add**
5. Finally, click **Apply** and then **OK**

Comment: To add some detail - for those not aware there is a setting in the zone that allows automatic logon.  If you open the "custom level", you will find a setting for "automatic logon with the current user name and password" and/or "Allow logon only from intranet zone" this is what allows that to happen.  Note - if you are only configured to allow logons from Intranet zone - than you need to add site to that zone and not to trusted sites (or update the settings).

Comment: Can I add your comment as details?